# Where / How ElasticSearch stores logs received from Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, storage, elastic-stack

*Disclaimer: I am **very new** to ELK Stack, so this question can be very basic.*

I am setting up ELK stack now. I have below **basic** questions about **ElasticSearch**.

1. What is the **storage model** elastic search is following?

*For example Oracle is using relational model ,Alfresco is using "document model" and Apache Jackrabbit is using "hierarchial model"*

2.Log data stored in elastic search is **persistent/permanent** ? Or ElasticSearch **deletes** log data after certain period?

3.How we will **manage/backup** this data?

4.Log/data files in Elastic Search is **human-readable**?

Any help/route to documentation will be appreciated.

Comment: In your title, the logs are the logs from Elasticsearch or logs received when using ELK for logs centralisation?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html

Comment: I meant logs received through Logstash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. the storage model is a Document model. Everything is a [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/document.html). The documents are of a particular type and they are stored in an [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_add_an_index.html).
2. Data send to ES is stored on disk. It can be then [read](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html), [searched](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) or [deleted](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html) through a REST API.
3. The Data is managed through the rest API. Usually for log centralisation, the logs are stored in date-based index (one index for today, one for yesterday and so on), so to delete the logs from one day, you delete the relevant [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-management.html). [Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html) can help in this case. ES offers a [backup and restore module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/modules-snapshots.html).
4. To access the data in ES, you'll have to use the REST API or use the [Kibana client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index.html).

Documentation:
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html

Comment: Thanks @baudsp, 2.Any data will be automatically deleted by ES? If I don't delete, it will stay forever, right?

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy The data sent to ES is stored on disk. So as long you don't delete the data through the API or on disk, ES keeps it.

Comment: I would remove "...or on disk..." as it's not advised to mess up with the data folders directly.